# Rename all files in directory, replacing backslash with forward slash, creating directory where needed

Tags: python, python-3.x

ATM, I have a directory of various files with backslashes in the file names, creating new directories where needed.

I have:

```
directory 'test'
| 'folder\screenshot.png'
| 'folder\screenshot_2.png'
| 'folder_other\screenshot_3.png
```

I am looking for:

```
directory 'test_'
| directory 'folder'
     | 'screenshot.png'
     | 'screenshot_2.png'
| directory 'folder_other'
     | 'screenshot_3.png'
```

I have tried the following but keep getting the error  `No such file or directory: 'folder_other\\screenshot.png'`

```
import shutil

for file in os.listdir('test'):
    src = file
    dst = file.replace('\\','/').replace('test', 'test_')
    ret = shutil.move(src, dst)

print(ret)
```

Comment: you need to join the file names from `listdir` onto the path passed into it.  note that using `pathlib.Path` often makes things like this much easier, I'd suggesting checking out https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) from the Python standard library to move conveniently manipulate file paths. This is generally recommend over manipulating paths as strings.

Using `pathlib`, it's relatively easy to convert between the source and target file paths, and to [recursively create the parent directories](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir) prior to moving the file.

```py
import pathlib

base = pathlib.Path.cwd()
source_base = base.joinpath("test")
target_base = base.joinpath("test_")

for file in source_base.iterdir():
    target_path = target_base.joinpath(*file.name.split("\\"))

    target_path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    file.rename(target_path)
```

Before:

```
test
├── folder_other\screenshot_3.png
├── folder\screenshot_2.png
└── folder\screenshot.png
```

After:

```
test
test_
├── folder
│   ├── screenshot_2.png
│   └── screenshot.png
└── folder_other
    └── screenshot_3.png
```